# Is there a way to override the Ping Maximum Response Time - IIS 10 for a specific process

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis

Our ping maximum response time is set to 90 seconds.  We have one transaction that is taking too long to complete.  Is there a way to temporarily override the setting? Or dynamically use the `httpRuntime executionTimeout` for a specific transaction?

Comment: You need to know that IIS settings are isolated from ASP.NET settings. Thus, `httpRuntime` tag under `system.web` won't control any part of IIS but merely ASP.NET runtime. You didn't reveal what exactly is the "ping maximum response time" in your context. If you are talking about "pingResponseTime" in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.applicationhost/applicationpools/add/processmodel then that setting is already at process level (all processes of the same application pool).

Comment: You need to find the problem first and then fix it, I suggest you open a case via: https://support.microsoft.com.

Comment: IIS settings has ping max response time set to 90seconds.  I read that I can override that value in my web.config using httpRuntime tag.  However I don't want to override everything, just one for api call.  Sorry for any confusion.

Comment: As far as I know, Ping Maximum Response Time is 90 seconds in IIS, and httpRuntime cannot override it.